# sqlsrv_fetch_object returns String data, right truncation

Tags: php, sql-server

I am using a select query to get data with `PHP` from `MSSQL` database. But when I am using `sqlsrv_fetch_object` I get the error: `String data, right truncation`. Its just a select query from a view, why I receive this message?

Here is my code:

```
$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,                            
                             "PWD"=>$pwd,                            
                             "Database"=>$databaseName); 

    /* Connect using SQL Server Authentication. */  
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);  

    $tsql = "SELECT custCode, custName, comments, incharge, currency, country, sellerID, sellerName, paymentMethod, category, dispatchMethod FROM [DataBase-Name].[dbo].[eshopCustomers]";

    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql,[],[ "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ]);
    if( $stmt === false) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
    }
    //number of results
    $num = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt);
    //if user is not in latest update then make him inactive
    $current_user_ids = [];
    if( $num > 0 ){
        for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++){
            $cst = sqlsrv_fetch_object($stmt); print_r($cst);
            if( $cst === false ) {
                die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
            } die();
...............................................................
```

Comment: That sounds like behavior that would occur at the DB as well. If you execute query direct from SQL you don't get that warning?

Comment: It's a view, so there's potentially code in the view that's triggering it.

Comment: When I run the query in MSSQL management studio there is no such an error ...